# Setup network permissions in a dorm network

Tags: linux, windows, networking, windows-xp, windows-7

I have a rather complex network idea that I would like to implement. I've done some google searches, but have been unable to find out how to pull this off. 
I live in a college dorm. All of these computers can see each other.

- Computer A: Main Desktop, has the files and printer that other computers want to access. Windows 7
- Computer B: My laptop, Windows 7.
- Computer C: Old desktop running linux as a HTPC.
- Computer D: Roommates Laptop windows 7
- Computer E: Friends laptop with Windows XP.
- Computers F: Other people on the floor.
- I would like computer B to have both read and write access on A, and to be able to print. Require some sort of authentication.
- I would like computer C to read files on A. Authentication would be nice,  but not a deal breaker.
- I would like computer D to have read access for files, and printer access, Require authentication.
- I would like computer E to have read access for the files.
- I want computers F to have access nothing.

Any answers or links to guides would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Enable file and print sharing, create accounts and assign desired rights as described to the accounts per file and print shares.

Comment: What he said.  If you're open to the network who cares - just set up proper user accounts with secure passwords.